# sum of terms of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $$F(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^t\frac{4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}$$ find $F(60)$.

---

I tried manipulating the general term(of sequence) in the form $V(n)-V(n-1)$ to calculate the sum by cancellation but went nowhere. I also tried using the fact that $$2n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}{(\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1})}^2$$ Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Your sum seems to be ill defined, since no indexing terms seem to appear in the summand. Do you mean to have $i$ instead of $n$ in the summands?

Comment: yes, thanks i fixed it

Comment: I would multiply with $$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1} - \sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{2n+1} - \sqrt{2n-1}}$$ for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more details, we have that

$$\frac{2n+\sqrt{(4n^2-1)}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=\frac12\left({\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)$$

then

$$\frac{4n+\sqrt{(4n^2-1)}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=\frac12\left({\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)+\frac{2n}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=\\=\frac12\left({\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)+n\left({\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)=\\=\frac12(2n+1)\sqrt{2n+1}-\frac12(2n-1)\sqrt{2n-1}=\\$$

$$=\frac12\left(\sqrt{(2n+1)^3}-\sqrt{(2n-1)^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$T_n=\frac{4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}[2n+1)^{3/2}-(2n-1)^{3/2}]=$$
Next by Telescopic summing we get
$$S(60)=[121^{3/2}-1]/2=[1331-1]/2=665$$