# How do you write ${r \over (r+1)!}$ as a difference?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

We are asked to evaluate the following sum

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty {r\over (r+1)!}$$

I thought it best to write the expression out as a difference and use the method of differences to find the sum.

However, how would one go about converting it into a difference? I lucked upon the solution, as it turns out:

$$
{r\over (r+1)!} \equiv {1 \over r!} - {1\over (r+1)!}
$$

But it was simply a result of me playing about and was not rigorous at all. What would've been a sure-fire method to reach this? More generally how should one approach expression like these when looking to convert them into differences, similar to how converting some expressions like ${1\over 4r^2-1 }$ into partial fractions can ease the solution?

Comment: Think of it as $\frac{r+1-1}{(r+1)!}$ and the result follows.

Comment: What do you call the "method of differences" ? In what way does it apply here ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust http://mathsathawthorn.pbworks.com/f/The+Method+of+Differences+pdf.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard trick that involves adding and subtracting the same number (often $1$) to make things line up. In this case
$$
\frac{r}{(r+1)!}=\frac{r+1-1}{(r+1)!}\\
=\frac{r+1}{(r+1)!}-\frac{1}{(r+1)!}\\
=\frac{1}{r!}-\frac{1}{(r+1)!}
$$
How would one discover this? Well, we would really like to have $r+1$ in the numerator, because that would cancel very nicely with the denominator. So we make it so that we have $r+1$ in the numerator, by adding $1$, and then subtracting $1$. The rest is standard arithmetic manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Well in case of factorials it is always a good idea to use the method of comparing coefficients.$$\frac{r}{(r+1)!}=\frac {A}{(r)!}-\frac{A}{(r+1))!}$$

The rest is just comparing coefficients.

The pointis to bring it of the form of $|f(r)-f(r+1)|$

In case of   $$\frac{1}{4r^2-1}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(r-1/2)(r+1/2)}=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{A}{r-1/2}-\frac{A}{r+1/2})$$

Sometimes it gets harder:say we have to find $$\sum r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$$

In this case we can  write $T_r=r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4-(r-1))$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)-(r-1)(r)(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)=V(r-1)-V(r)$$

The summary is in case consecutive coefficients come trying to manipulate a constant term to the form $r+k-r$ sometimes works.

> Exercise:Evaluate $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

Hint:

> use partial fractions $$\frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{A}{r}-\frac{B}{r+1}+\frac{C}{r+2}$$

Although some times we have to think a bit differently as in this problem: [sum of terms of series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775757/sum-of-terms-of-series)

Answer (score 1):

I would not say "writing out the expression as a difference", but more "turning it into more familiar terms". There is no general method for this.

In $\dfrac r{(r+1)!}$ we don't see a simplification, because we need $r+1$ at the numerator. So we can use an artifice and write

$$\dfrac r{(r+1)!}=\dfrac{r+1-1}{(r+1)!}=\frac1{r!}-\frac1{(r+1)!}$$ and voilà, by chance. We now can work out the partial $e$ series.